# Set a specific date and time in javascript independant of the browser timezone and time

Tags: javascript, date, time

My Problem seems simple but I couldn't find a decent simple solution yet.
Usecase:
Anyone in the world should be able to access a website and with a button set a date to 3, 5 or 10 days in the future, 23:59:59 in GERMANY.
This should be independant of the browser location or a wrong date / time setting on the client browser.
I can get the server date / time via php inject which i can use as reference. So ideally i can just work with that but as soon as i do any operation with the date it is always handled in the timezone of the browser. So if i set the time to 23:59:59 then it is set according to browser timezone.
Any idea how to just work with a timezone independant of the browser?
Summertime should also be considered.

Basically i need a function like:
SetDate(Today_In_Germany + x days at 23:59:59)

Example code:

```
var t_date =  new Date(); 
t_date.setDate(t_date.getDate() + 5)); //Add 5 days to current day
t_date.setHours(23,59,00,00); //Set it to 23:59
```

This works perfectly well within one timezone. But if you access the function from a different timezone it will set it to 23:59 of the timezone you are in, not the timezone of Germany which i want to set. Plus if your computer clock is wrong i get the wrong time.

Comment: Do you consider Central European Summer Time and Central European Time?

Comment: This should also be considered. Yes, forgot to mention about that.

Comment: TBH I don't understand the problem. Can you provide a [mcve]? Let's say I'm in Australia and I click on the +3 button in 3 hours (28.09.2021 00:24). 3 days in the future is 01.10.2021 00:24. What do you expect now? 01.10.2021 23:59:59 or 30.09.2021 23:59:59?

Comment: As far as I know, JavaScript `Date` object doesn't provide that feature (random time zones) out of the box, it only handles UTC and local time zone (in a confusing way, but that's another story). You'll have to encapsulate your dates in a custom wrapper. I presume well known date libraries will provide that.

Comment: I think I would send the current timestamp with time zone (28.09.2021 00:24 GMT+10) and the value (+3 days) to the backend and do the calculations there.

Comment: @jabaa: I have added a code snippet to explain better. But i likely follow your recommendation and just call a php page to do that calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Date` object doesn't have that feature. New [temporal proposal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/) does.

```
let dt = Temporal.ZonedDateTime.from({
  timeZone: 'Europe/Berlin',
  year: 2021,
  month: 9,
  day: 27,
  hour: 23,
  minute: 59,
  second: 59
})
```

Without Temporal, you need library like MomentJS.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what i was looking for and hope it will make it somewhen to be included in Javascript. Until then i likely do the processing with server-side scripts.

Comment: it will definitely be in JavaScript, it's most of the way through the process

Answer (score 0):

Until the Temporal implementation Barney mentioned is released i will use jabaas approach slightly modified.
I inject the unix timestamp of Germany's today 23:59:59 via server side script. Then i can freely add 60x60x24 seconds for each day in the future and i will not get confused with Timezones.
Not the solution i initally wanted but a solution which works for me.